# Use existing facebook access tokens with graph API

Tags: facebook, parse-platform

How can I use the existing facebook access token without additional authentication. I have a server system which will give valid facebook access tokens to clients.

The flow looks like this:

1. Client redirects user to facebook through server API
2. User authenticates
3. Server API handles redirect
4. Server API sends access_token to client (via WebSockets)
5. Client does job with graph API

Is this possible when using parse.com? (IOs and Android SDKs)